# Does HEAP mean the same thing with a table that has Non-Clustered index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, non-clustered-index, heap-table

In terms of SQL terminology, does HEAP stands for a table that has Non-Clustered index?

Or there is a nuance or it has completely a different meaning?

Comment: A heap table is a table that has no clustered index. Only one index can be the clustered index so if a table has more than one index, only one of them may be the clustered index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A heap can have either no index at all or a non-clustered index. But a clustered table can also have non-clustered indexs on top so -

> does HEAP stands for a table that has Non-Clustered index?

is not a great definition as a table with a non-clustered index could be either a clustered table or a heap.

Answer (score 0):

A heap is a table without a clustered index. Simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

A heap is a table without a clustered index. Heaps have one row in `sys.partitions`, with `index_id = 0` for each partition used by the heap. By default, a heap has a single partition. When a heap has multiple partitions, each partition has a heap structure that contains the data for that specific partition.